# How to group my account balance by weeks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model Account which will see the balance grows by activities. Is there a way to group and get the final balance for that week? An example here:

Account

```
created_at: 31 April 2016, balance: 8000  # Saturday
created_at: 1 May 2016, balance: 7500     # Sunday
created_at: 1 May 2016, balance: 7000     # Sunday
created_at: 7 May 2016, balance: 5000     # Saturday
created_at: 7 May 2016, balance: 4000     #    "
created_at: 8 May 2016, balance: 3500     # Sunday
created_at: 12 May 2016, balance: 7000    # Thursday
```

And lets say the end point of week will be every Monday. My expected result will be:

```
{
  2 May 2016 => 7000,    # Monday
  9 May 2016 => 3500,    # Monday
  13 May 2016 => 7000    # Today
}
```

I want the balance on each Monday, but with the addition of the most recent balance, even if it is not on a Monday.

Comment: `created_at` seems to be a `Date`, is that correct? (default would be a `Time`)

Comment: I don't understand the keys in your result hash and the way the sums are calculated. 9 May 2016 is a Monday and 13 May 2016 is a Friday. I would have expected identical week days. Furthermore, why does the sum for 9 May 2016 include the balance for Sun, 08 May 2016, but not the balance for Sat, 07 May 2016?

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your reply. It is the default created_at so it should be datetime, I just summarised it in my example. I am trying to get the last balance so it should be 3500. There might also be more than one account activity per day and my goal is to get the final balance of that week, which will be the closest balance to 9 May.

Comment: I still don't understand.  I've annotated the data with weekdays to try to illustrate the confusion that @Stefan and I have.  Can you please edit the question to make it clearer what it is you want?

Comment: @WayneConrad I have added more details to the question. So there are 3 more activities for the week before 2 May, and I would like to get the ending balance, which is `7000` and write them into the hash, so that would be `2 May 2016 => 7000`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited the question to be more explicit about the final balance.  With that, the question is clear enough--I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: The word "sum" in you title still irritates me. You don't calculate any sums (adding multiple numbers), do you?

Comment: @Stefan Sorry that was my bad. I have edited the title.

Answer (score 1):

Group the results by week of the year, and the year:

```
.group("extract(dow from 'created_at'), extract(week from 'created_at')")
```

then select the sum of balance for this:

```
.select("sum(balance)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I get this error when trying to group: `ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique`. And I think I am getting the last balance on that week, not the sum of the balances.